# Unable to access AppEngine Application running in Android Studio using mobile browser

Tags: android, android-studio, google-app-engine

I'm running Google AppEngine Application in Android Studio.
My Computer and Android Mobile (Google Pixel) are connected to same LAN network.

When I try to access AppEngine application in Android Mobile Browser with IP Address of my computer, getting "The connection has timed out" error.

I found the IP Address of my computer using `ipconfig` command. I was able to access application in the same computer browser with the IP Address.

Am I missing any configuration ?

Comment: Check the running configurations for the local server, often it comes with default serving `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. If so change it to `0.0.0.0`, which usually means serving other hosts on the networks as well.

Comment: @DanCornilescu My Server startup showing the below log. It is running `0.0.0.0` as --address.

`-Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Users\Awesome\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --address=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 `